# Group vertically and Horizontally in HighCharts Gantt

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to do, aparently, a simple thing which is to group tasks horizontally and vertically. I have followed the following official documentation:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/gantt/gantt-grouping-tasks

But, in my fiddle below, the task sections doesn't even appear in my "acceptance tests" task. My option is as following:

```
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Grouping in a hierarchy'
  }, 

  series: [{
    name: 'Project 1',
    data: [
      {
        // parent task
        name: 'Product Launch',
        id: 'launch',        
        // hide the subtasks
        // collapsed: true

        // use a smaller pointwidth for the parent task 
        pointWidth: 3
      }, {
        parent: 'launch',
        id: 'b',
        name: 'Develop',
        "start": 1560902400000,
            "end": 1561075200000
      }, {
        parent: 'launch',
        id: 'a',
        name: 'Run acceptance tests',
            data:[{start: 1560902400000,
            end: 1561075200000},{start: 1561507200000,
            end: 1561680000000}]


      }
    ]
  }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rdvaqgkh/

Any idea on why this is happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not nest data in that way. To have many points in one row, you need to set `yAxis.uniqueNames` to `true` and define points with the same name:

```
yAxis: {
    uniqueNames: true
},

series: [{
    data: [{
        // parent task
        name: 'Product Launch',
        id: 'launch',
        ...
    }, {
        parent: 'launch',
        id: 'b',
        name: 'Develop',
        ...
    }, {
        parent: 'launch',
        id: 'a',
        name: 'Run acceptance tests',
        ...
    }, {
        parent: 'launch',
        id: 'b',
        name: 'Run acceptance tests',
        ...
    }]
}]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9en0zq3L/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/yAxis.uniqueNames